# Is this the correct way to implement multithreading using the executor service?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to teach myself to use multithreading using the executor service and am wondering what the best practise would be to implement my code below - I'm reading a directory of text files and checking characters / words -

Also I'm confused whether multiple threads are being used if all i do is for each through the file list. Are multiple files being worked on at once?

Main class

```
public class Application {

    private long totalCharacterCount;
    private long totalLineCount;
    private final File[] fileList;
    private final static String _DIRECTORY = "src//documents";

    public Application(String directory){
        fileList = new File(directory).listFiles();
    }
    public synchronized File[] getFileList(){
        return fileList;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
           ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

          Application x = new Application(_DIRECTORY);

          for(File file : x.getFileList()){
               Future<FileReadings> response = executor.submit(new Process(file));
               x.totalCharacterCount += response.get().characterCount;
               x.totalLineCount += response.get().lineCount;

          }
          System.out.println("Total lines in all documents: " + x.totalLineCount);
          System.out.println("Total characters in all documents: " + x.totalCharacterCount);
          executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Process class

```
public class Process implements Callable<FileReadings> {

    private FileReadings object;
    private File file;
    public Process(File file){
        FileReadings obj = new FileReadings();
        this.object = obj;

        this.file = file;
    }

    public void CountCharacters(File file){
        int count = 0;
        try {

            BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file.toPath());
            while(reader.read() != -1){
                count++;
            }
            object.characterCount = reader.read();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
            object.characterCount = count;
    }
    public void CountLines(File file){
        try {
            Stream<String> text = Files.lines(file.toPath());
            object.lineCount = text.count();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public FileReadings call() throws Exception {
        CountCharacters(this.file);
        CountLines(this.file);
        System.out.println("THERE WERE: " + object.characterCount + " CHARACTERS IN: " + file.getName());
        System.out.println("THERE WERE: " + object.lineCount + " LINES IN: " + file.getName());
        return object;
    }
}
```

File readings class

```
public class FileReadings {
     long characterCount;
     long lineCount;
}
```

Results in:

```
THERE WERE: 65 CHARACTERS IN: test1.txt
THERE WERE: 10 LINES IN: test1.txt
THERE WERE: 88 CHARACTERS IN: test2.txt
THERE WERE: 21 LINES IN: test2.txt
Total lines in all documents: 31
Total characters in all documents: 153
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no. this is not the correct way. You submit one process and then by calling `get()` on the future, you block and wait for it to finish, so effectively it is a synchronous processing. 
There are two ways to do parallel, asynchronous processing:

1) `invokeAll()`

this is the easier method, but it requires that you create all the process instances in advance, so it depends on how many parallel tasks you want to execute (if you have millions of them, you might hit a memory limit). once you created the processes, you submit them at once to the executor. it will execute all tasks in parallel (according to thread pool size) and return when all are finished.

```
      List<Callable<FileReadings>> tasks = new Arraylist<>();
      for (File file : x.getFileList()) {
           tasks.add(new Process(file));
      }
      // submit all processes at once. they will be processed in parallel 
      // this call blocks until all tasks are finished
      List<Future<FileReadings>> responses = executor.invokeAll(tasks);
      // at this point all processes finished. all get() will return immediately
      for (Future<FileReadings> response : responses) {
           x.totalCharacterCount += response.get().characterCount;
           x.totalLineCount += response.get().lineCount;
      }
```

2) `submit()`

this solution is more scalable as you create a process and submit it immediately so the memory requirements are constant (excluding the executor). however, you need to manage the responses by yourself:

```
      List<Future<FileReadings>> responses = new ArrayList<>();
      for (File file : x.getFileList()) {
           responses.add(executor.submit(new Process(file)));
      }
      // at this point all processes submitted but not finished.
      // need to check which is finished at intervarls
      while (responses.isEmpty() == false) {
          Thread.sleep(1000);  // allow some processing time for tasks
          // ListIterator allows removing items
          ListIterator<Future<FileReadings>> itr = responses.listIterator();
          while (itr.hasNext()) {
               Future<FileReadings> response = itr.next();
               // if task is complete, get it and remove from list
               if (response.isDone()) {
                   x.totalCharacterCount += response.get().characterCount;
                   x.totalLineCount += response.get().lineCount;
                   itr.remove();
               }
          }
      }
```

Comment: I had a good feeling that it was all synchronous but I didn't really know how to change it. Your reply was a big help, thank you!